# Adding filter: grayscale to img elements hides overlaid elements

Tags: html, css

Due to some fun little style guide changes, all images must be black and white. I figured a global style would take care of this:

```
img {
    filter: grayscale(100%)
}
```

It works like a charm, however: Elements that sit on top of images suddenly vanish. Ex: Text sitting on top of a banner image disappears, and a `::before` element sitting on top of an image vanishes.

Is this expected behavior or is there something sinister going on?

EDIT:

The HTML is nothing special:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header-text">
        <h2>My Header Text</h2>
    </div>
    <img src="myimage.png" />
</div>
```

`.header-text` is positioned absolutely.

Comment: Please share your HTML

Comment: What elelemts disappear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter affects the stacking order which can be adjusted by giving a z-index value to the `header-text` div.

This is documented in the spec.

[**Filter Property**](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filters/#FilterProperty)

> A computed value of other than `none` results in the creation of a stacking context [CSS21] the same way that CSS opacity does.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.header-text {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

img {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header-text">
    <h2>My Header Text</h2>
  </div>
  <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300?image=1" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I can't comment, only answer (due to points and stuff)

If element has filter initially, its children will use this element as containing block.
If filter has dynamically added to element, then it will hide overflowing children.

Try putting a class into your img and doing the grayscale only in there, it may do the trick. Also, a z-index may help.